# entity_load based on language selection

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I have a node for different language, but I would like to load node for "en" language only using `entity_load` after firing entity query.

How can I achieve it using this function in Drupal 7

Comment: I have just used this function, but when i am in china country it takes nodes details from china country ,actually i dont need nodes from china, i just use english node details. can we get it ? entity_load('node', array_keys($entities['node']));

Comment: try to change the default language in your setup, like in [this post] (https://www.drupal.org/node/1319238)

Comment: Sorry I can't do this, In my international site i just want one page in which i just need to load english nodes only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [i18n module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) then you should be able to create a new content type for this node and set the language to EN under the "Multilingual Settings" tab.